# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hamweather.aeris.maps.R$layout using Aeris Weather SDK

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using the Hamweather Aeris Andorid SDK, and I am trying to implement the map view component. When I follow their online tutorials, I can not render the AerisMapView, and I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hamweather.aeris.maps.R$layout.
```

Does anyone know where this is coming from/how to fix it?

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView
        android:id="@+id/aerisfragment_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class MapViewActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mapview_activity);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

Finally, the fragment:

```
import android.location.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.hamweather.aeris.communication.AerisCallback;
import com.hamweather.aeris.communication.EndpointType;
import com.hamweather.aeris.location.LocationHelper;
import com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView;
import com.hamweather.aeris.maps.AerisMapView.AerisMapType;
import com.hamweather.aeris.maps.MapViewFragment;
import com.hamweather.aeris.maps.interfaces.OnAerisMapLongClickListener;
import com.hamweather.aeris.maps.interfaces.OnAerisMarkerInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.hamweather.aeris.maps.markers.AerisMarker;
import com.hamweather.aeris.model.AerisResponse;
import com.hamweather.aeris.response.EarthquakesResponse;
import com.hamweather.aeris.response.FiresResponse;
import com.hamweather.aeris.response.StormCellResponse;
import com.hamweather.aeris.response.StormReportsResponse;

public class MapFragment extends MapViewFragment implements OnAerisMapLongClickListener, AerisCallback,
    OnAerisMarkerInfoWindowClickListener{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_tab_site_weather2,
            container, false);
    mapView = (AerisMapView) view.findViewById(R.id.aerisfragment_map);
    mapView.init(savedInstanceState, AerisMapType.GOOGLE);
    initMap();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return view;
}

/**
 * Inits the map with specific setting
 */
private void initMap() {
    mapView.moveToLocation(new LatLng(34.7, -86.7), 9);
    mapView.setOnAerisMapLongClickListener(this);
    mapView.setOnAerisWindowClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onResult(EndpointType endpointType, AerisResponse aerisResponse) {

}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(double v, double v1) {

}

@Override
public void wildfireWindowPressed(FiresResponse firesResponse, AerisMarker aerisMarker) {

}

@Override
public void stormCellsWindowPressed(StormCellResponse stormCellResponse, AerisMarker aerisMarker) {

}

@Override
public void stormReportsWindowPressed(StormReportsResponse stormReportsResponse, AerisMarker aerisMarker) {

}

@Override
public void earthquakeWindowPressed(EarthquakesResponse earthquakesResponse, AerisMarker aerisMarker) {

}
}
```

Also, this is my first Q on stack exchange, so if I failed to adhere to a certain convention or etiquette, please let me know, and I'll try to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to get it working. For anyone who has this issue, here were my steps:

I first switched from using the jars to using the gradle dependency. Per their website, add the following to your build.gradle(the module one)

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
    compile 'com.hamweather:aeris-maps-library:1.0.0@aar'
}
```

Also be sure to add the following, in the andorid tag, which probably already exists in the file:

```
android {

    ...some other stuff...

    dexOptions{
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
```

Double check that you have the proper API key permissions for google maps. Then it works. As far as I can tell, it had something to do with using the compiled jar, not the repo version.